# Exit all functions from code in inner function

Tags: c#

If I have nested functions in C#, how to exit from both function at once when executing inner function code. (`Return;` only exits from executing function.)

```
public void Function1()
{
    Function2();
}

public void Function2()
{
    if (1 == 1)
    {       
        //Exit from both functions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use return codes instead of void functions.  Function1 can return if Function2 fails like so:

```
public void Function1()
{
    if (Function2() == false)
        return;

    // do other code if Function2 succeeded
}

public bool Function2()
{
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to return from a stack of functions simultaneously is to throw an exception.
An exception will work it's way down the call stack until it finds an appropriate handler.

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
}

public void FunctionZero()
{
   try
   {
      Trace.WriteLine("Function0 - Calling Function 1");
      Function1();
      Trace.WriteLine("Function0 - Function1 has returned");
   }
   catch(MyExceptionType ex)
   {
      Trace.WriteLine("Function0 - in the exception handler");
   }
}

public void Function1()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Function1 - Calling Function 2");
    Function2();
    Trace.WriteLine("Function1 - Function2 has returned");
}

public void Function2()
{
    if (1==1)
    {
       // This will jump to the exception handler in function zero
       Trace.WriteLine("Function2 - throwing an exception");
       throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

Thiw will create the following trace output

> Function0 - Calling Function 1
>
> Function1 - Calling Function 2
>
> Function2 - Throwing an exception
>
> Function0 - In the exception handler

While you CAN do this, it's not necessarily a good idea. Standard coding practice is for Exceptions only to be used in exceptional circumstances, and not for normal flow control.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your functions do. This might help, if it fits in your scenario.

```
public void Function1()
{
    if(!Function2())
    {
      return;
    }
}

public bool Function2()
{
    if (1 == 1)
    {   
        return false;  //Exit from both functions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just return a boolean to indicate success:

```
public void Function1()
{
    if(Function2())
    {
       //..
    }
}

public bool Function2()
{
    if (1 == 1)
    {       
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```